# how to replace a div according to size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find (and later replace) all the divs with certain width. I don't have an id or a class.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
var width = $(this).width();
if (width > 400) {
    $(this).hide();
    console.log($(this));
}
});
```

Comment: It should work, http://jsfiddle.net/cbPKX/ , maybe you just forget to import jquery library or all your divs have width<401

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier method is

```
$('div').filter(function(){ return $(this).width() > 400 });
```

That will select all divs that are larger than `400px`

You can hide them using

```
$('div').filter(function(){ return $(this).width() > 400 }).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by following function

```
        $( "div" ).each(function() {
            if($(this).width()>400)
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
```

It will traverse all div which has width greater than 400 and hide it.